# Creating a MongoDB 'find' query to search between a specific number of matching documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using the MongoDB NodeJS driver and need to search the database for a specific set of posts. However if the post count gets too big I want to search between perhaps the 50th - 100th set of matching posts with the query and return the value to the client. However would searching for so many documents and returning them serve as a performance issue? If so what would be the proper query term?

Answer (score 1):

Sample using skip/limit:

```
//1st part    
db.dummy.find().limit(10)
//2nd part
db.dummy.find().skip(10).limit(10)
```

Take a look at the mongodb documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

limit: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit

skip:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#cursor.skip

Answer (score 0):

You can use Skip and limit
skip the first 49 objects , then limit it by 50 
then you will get what you want !

I hope this will help you ,